# I used useLazyQuery in functional component, but I need to use the same with class component. How can I do it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I have some functional component '' with 3 checkboxes and 1 button. I used hook useLazyQuery that my query was sent after clicking on button. I did it. But my component is rerendered every times when I click to button. That's why I got recommend to redo my functional component to class component. But I don't know how to rewrite my functions inside of functional component

```
const generateQuery = (checkboxNameChecked: boolean, checkboxPatronymicChecked: boolean, checkboxSurnameChecked: boolean) => 
    `query { me { id ${checkboxNameChecked ? 'name ' : ''}` +
    `${checkboxPatronymicChecked ? 'patronymic ' : ''}` +
    `${checkboxSurnameChecked ? 'surname' : ''} }}`;

//some code

const Form: React.FC<LaunchesProps> = () => {
    const checkboxName = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    //the same

    const customStringQuery = generateQuery(checkboxName.current && 
        checkboxName.current.checked ? true: false,
        //the same);

    const GET_USER = gql([customStringQuery]);
    const [getUser, { data, loading, error }] = 
    useLazyQuery<UserDetailsTypes.UserDetails,UserDetailsTypes.UserDetails_user>(
        GET_USER,
        { fetchPolicy: "no-cache" }
    );
    const getData = () => {
        var res = ``;
        if(data && data.me && data.me.name){res+=`${data.me.name} `}
        //the same
        if(loading) return `loading`
        if(error) return `error`
        return res;
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        textInput.current!.value = getData();
    })
    return (
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose fields</legend>
            //some html
            <button onClick={()=>getUser()}>Show</button>
            <input
                type="text"
                ref={textInput}
            />
    </fieldset>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: graphql abusing - `generateQuery`! graphql shouldn't be created by string manipulations - use variables - read docs

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your class component with a functional component that uses the hook and then pass down the `getUser` function as a prop.

```
const WrapperComponent = () => {
  const [getUser] = useLazyQuery(GET_USER)

  return <YourClassComponent getUser={getUser}/>
}
```

However, you should keep in mind that converting your functional component to a class component will not impact how many times your component is rendered unless you correctly implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` method or use `PureComponent`.

If you want to optimize a functional component, instead of using `shouldComponentUpdate`, you can use `React.memo` to achieve a similar effect as shown [here in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate). If you have costly calculations on each render you're trying to avoid, you can also use the `useMemo` hook to memoize them.